# How does a compiler knows not to move the code inside a critical section to the outside of the critical section?

Tags: c, winapi

Based on my understanding:

- A compiler can do whatever re-ordering it wants to my code.
- The code inside a critical section will not be moved to the outside of the critical section.

Now say I have the following code:

```
printf("Hi");

EnterCriticalSection(&CriticalSection);
printf("Inside the critical section");
printf("Also inside the critical section");
LeaveCriticalSection(&CriticalSection);

printf("Bye");
```

Now, will the compiler actually look for the functions `EnterCriticalSection()` and `LeaveCriticalSection()` and not move the code inside of them to the outside?

Comment: The compiler knows nothing about your critical section. It operates at a much more micro-level than that. It operates at the assembly level. It may move individual assembly instructions to be outside the critical section. But it will not affect the correctness of your code as that's one of its core guarantees.

Comment: It is pretty simple, it cannot do "whatever re-ordering".  The optimizer will not move code across a function call that it doesn't know beans about.  It has to assume it has observable side-effects.  Just like it will never print "Bye" before "Hi".

Comment: @Hans Passant So even if I used `foo()` and `boo()` instead of `EnterCriticalSection()` and `LeaveCriticalSection()`, the code inside `foo()` and `boo()` will not be moved outside of these two functions, correct?

Comment: compiler have no knowledge about `EnterCriticalSection` or `LeaveCriticalSection` api. `EnterCriticalSection` or `foo` or `boo` - no any different for compiler. and any external function call - stop any re-ordering. compiler can do reordering only in code snippet, not containing any external calls. first external call some `boo` - stoping reordering and act as memory barrier

Comment: `the code inside foo() and boo() will not be moved outside of these two functions, correct?` - of course will be not moved. compiler never re-order external functions calls and code between this calls. it can only reorder some instructions in code snippet where *no any external calls*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> A compiler can do whatever re-ordering it wants to my code.

This is incorrect.  The compiler is limited.

> The code inside a critical section will not be moved to the outside of the critical section.

This is also incorrect, depending on what code is inside / outside the critical section.

### Optimization and constraints

The compiler has a bunch of constraints about each piece of code in your function.  These constraints might be inputs and outputs (can't execute Y unless you execute X first) or more general statements like "this affects the contents of memory somewhere".  The compiler will preserve these constraints when compiling your code.  If the compiler doesn't know what a function does it will use the heaviest set of constraints.

*In general,* this means that the compiler won't flip the order of two function calls<sup>1</sup>.

```
f(); // Maybe affects memory somewhere.
g(); // Maybe affects memory somewhere.
```

It also means that generally, if you access memory, those memory accesses have to be sequenced relative to the function calls.

```
void myfunc(X *ptr) {
    my_lock(ptr->mutex);   // Maybe affects memory somewhere.
    ptr->field++;          // Definitely affects memory at ptr->field.
    my_unlock(ptr->mutex); // Maybe affects memory somewhere.
}
```

However, it can reorder things out of critical sections:

```
int i = 5;
my_lock();   // Maybe affects memory somewhere.
i++;         // This is not "memory somewhere", this is my variable,
             // it's a register or on the stack and nobody else can
             // change it.
my_unlock(); // Maybe affects memory somewhere.
```

So it could reorder that to:

```
int i = 6;
my_lock();
my_unlock();
```

The above code can be reordered because the compiler has special knowledge about who is allowed to modify `i`.  If you have some special code somewhere else which walks up the stack to try and create a pointer to `i` even though `&i` never appears in your program, you're breaking your contract with the compiler (a.k.a. your program has undefined behavior).

I hope this clarifies things.

#### Footnote

<sup>1</sup>: You can add annotations like `__declspec(noalias)` which change this rule, and LTO / whole-program-optimization / interprocedural optimization can change things too.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing the compiler doesn't have any special knowledge about EnterCriticalSection;  it won't be able to make any assumptions about what the function does.

Therefore it cannot reorder the `printf` statements because it has to allow for the possibility that `EnterCriticalSection` might also write to `stdout`, and the output on `stdout` has to appear in the same order as if the `printf` statements were executed as written.

The same applies to things like access to global variables, the compiler has to allow for the function maybe accessing such variables.